# How to ensure double quote in multiline strings

Tags: python, wtforms

I wrote an SQL query which uses data passed in from WTForms as parameters.
How do I ensure double quotes on the variable?

```
q = """
select * from table
where dt_date >= %(date)s""" % {'date':date}
```

Right now it shows as

```
select * from table
where dt_date >= 23-06-2016
```

which then throws error. How to make it become:

```
select * from table
where dt_date >= "23-06-2016"
```

Comment: You could put literal double quotes into your triple-quoted string.

Comment: does it have to be double quotes or would single `'` quotes work too? If single quotes would work I'd recommend using `%(date)r` instead of `s` to get the code representation of the string (including string quotes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python doesn't stop you from using double-quotes inside your multiline strings. The trouble is only when you place them next to each other (`""""`). You can either escape your double quotes as `\"` or simply leave a space between them and the triple-quotes (`" """`).

**Escaping:**

```
q = """
select * from table
where dt_date >= \"%(date)s\""""%{'date':date}
>>> print q

select * from table
where dt_date >= "asdf"
```

**Space before the triple-quotes:**

```
q = """
select * from table
where dt_date >= "%(date)s" """%{'date':date}
>>> print q

select * from table
where dt_date >= "asdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the double quotes in your multine.

```
>>> q = """
... select * from table
... where dt_date >= \"%(date)s\""""%{'date':date}
>>> q
'\nselect * from table\nwhere dt_date >= "23-06-2016"'
>>> print q

select * from table
where dt_date >= "23-06-2016"
```